# Online Accounts in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: facebook, online-accounts

When I head to Online Accounts and try to add Facebook, it asks me to enter username and password, then save the device by giving it a name, but then the blue circle spins around for a second or two then I get a blank page and Facebook isn't being added.

It was working before I removed it, so I'm not sure what's happening.

Anyone got an idea of what I can do?

Comment: Go to facebook and check for the application asking permissions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was dealing with the same problem and foud the solution miself ;)

1. You need to go to privacy settings on your facebook account, at **Ads, Apps and Websites ->Edit Settings->Apps you Use->Edit Settings**  and **Remove** Ubuntu
2. go to **System Settings** and add again the facebook **Online Account**

and it will work

Answer (score 0):

in **facebook** go to **App Center-->My Apps** and remove **Ubuntu**.
now add your **facebook online account**.. it will work :) :)