# Can't connect facebook to online accounts in 13.04

Tags: facebook, online-accounts

Just install 13.04 and am having trouble setting up online accounts with facebook. It opens up firefox and when I log in it comes up with a security warning. Any ideas why this is or what I could do to fix it?

Comment: I guess this is an issue in Facebook's authentication and authorization services since other user report similar issues: http://askubuntu.com/questions/295644/security-warning-from-facebook-in-chromium

Comment: Some users have suggested that disabling some of Facebook's "Secure Connection" settings within their accounts directly through Facebook has resolved a lot of the 3rd-party apps and API calls that have failed lately.  Worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks, already gave that a go but it didn't make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: I'm having this problem and I'm not even trying to connect to Facebook.  It seems to be happening when I launch Skype.

Comment: Not sure exactly why this worked but I eventually got it working. here are the steps: 1. disable secure connection on facebook security preferences, 2. remove the ubuntu app from your facebook apps page if it is there, 3. sign out of facebook, 4. open online account and add a facebook account. Firefox should open as before, but then go back to the online accounts page, right click in the space where the page usually loads and select reload. Should work from there. Random!

Comment: Didn't work for me. Been trying it for ages. Anyone got anything that might work? I found two [other](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206734/online-accounts-in-ubuntu-12-10) [questions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/259528/online-accounts-in-12-10-facebook-not-working) and two [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/signon-ui/+bug/1132296) [reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center-signon/+bug/1132030) but no-one seems to have a reliable fix.

Comment: Didn't work for me too, it simply open the default browser instead of load facebook on signon-ui, any solution yet?

Comment: Tried the quick fix from mark howard and sadly it didn't work for me either. Wishing this issue was resolved, it's been like this for a while now.

Answer (score 8):

There's a bug filed for this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1180297

The root cause is that Facebook redirects to an insecure HTTP page during the authentication process, and for security reasons we don't allow that. The same problem appeared in February, and then Facebook was quick to fix it in a few days. Now it seems it's taking longer, but I'm still hopeful.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I managed to get connected with my work around but it drops the connections now and again, which I guess must be related.

Answer (score 7):

the temporary solution for this as on launchpad page is to add the lines

`<setting name="AllowedSchemes" type="as">['https','http']</setting>`

to the file /usr/share/accounts/providers/facebook.provider

but it has got security risks.

Comment: I did this just to set it up, and then removed the line.

Comment: That does not make difference in the problem of security risks. Also even after connecting you will some times recieve a notification that Failed to connect to <facebook account> error. Facebook has got issues with external messengers, hope they sort it out soon.

Comment: The only difference it makes is that I know when it is connecting insecurely. I can minimize exposure for the one brief connection to authenticate, and then disallow it from using http (w/o ssl) when I'm on a public network. There are still risks, but they are smaller and calculated.